# Unreachable code block (in python) with html templater

Tags: python, html, conditional-statements, scope

I'm having trouble creating a fiddly html table in python 3.4. The templater is [html 1.16](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html/). Here's a simplified version of the problem: I would like to traverse a list. For each list item, I would like to write the data to a html table. The table should be two columns wide.

```
from html import HTML
#create html object
h = HTML()
comments=["blah1",
         "blah2",
         "blah3"
         ]

#create table object
c_table = h.table.tbody
for i, comment in enumerate(comments):
    #create row if we are at an odd index
    if i % 2 != 0:
        row = c_table.tr
        row.td(comment)
    else:
        #it is intended to add another <td> to the current row here
        #but because the row was declared in the if block, it is out of scope 
        row.td(comment)

#write the html output now
print(h)
```

The difficulty is with the templater, specifically: accessing the row object for the second cell of the row without causing the `</tr>` closing tag. I have to create new cells through the `row` object, otherwise if I call `c_table.tr.td` it closes the row with `</tr>` and starts a new one.

Can anyone clever think of any code trickery that achieves what I'm trying to do in these  circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment is simply incorrect. Python does not have block scope, and the row that is defined in the if block is accessible in the else.

In fact, you can take the td out of the if block, and remove the else altogether.

Comment: Your answer seems to be incorrect. If I take the `row.td(comment)` out of the block and remove the `else` block, I get `NameError: name 'row' is not defined`. Likewise if I run the code as is. The sample code should be pastable straight into your interpreter...

Comment: That's because your logic is wrong. Indexes are 0-based, so the first time through the loop `i % 2` is 0, and row does not get defined. You should change that `!=` to `==`.

Comment: Got it. Huge facepalm on my part. Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that row object, because it was created inside the first if. In order to access it in your "else", you'll have to create it outside both clauses, which doesn't help you achieve your goal.

Try dividing the list into "chunks" - a list of lists with 2 objects each.

```
h = HTML()
comments=["blah1",
         "blah2",
         "blah3",
         "blah4",
         "blah5"
         ]

fixed_list = []
for i in xrange(0, len(comments), 2):
    fixed_list.append(comments[i:i+2])
```

Now fixed list looks like this -

```
[["blah1", "blah2"], ["blah3", "blah4"], .....]
```

And now you can easily iterate over that list, and create a row for each list -

```
#create table object
body = h.body
tb = body.table

for comments_list in fixed_list:
    row = tb.tr
    for comment in comments_list:
        row.td(comment)

print h
```